# Deleted record are not giving me their ID back

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, record, delete-row

If I delete a record from my table, and then create a new record, it does dot reuse the ID from the deleted records - leaving gaps in sequential IDs. Can anyone help with this?
I believe the affected code is here:

```
def Delete():
    #open database
    Database()
    if not tree.selection():
        tkMessageBox.showwarning("Warning","Select data to delete")
    else:
        result = tkMessageBox.askquestion('Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?',
                                          icon="warning")
        if result == 'yes':
            curItem = tree.focus()
            contents = (tree.item(curItem))
            selecteditem = contents['values']
            tree.delete(curItem)
            cursor=conn.execute("DELETE FROM REGISTRATION WHERE RID = %d" % selecteditem[0])
            conn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
```

Here is my output - notice the gaps in sequence where records were deleted:

[image]

Comment: that's an expected behavior in pretty much all database engines for many reasons (foreign key integrity out of the top of my head, there are others). Why does it bother you?

Comment: @Marat - Not really, but I thought it was abnormal behavior, as another I used did not do that. If I deleted record 1, the next record input would go in that slot. I'm a beginner, so chalk it up to inexperience.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite defines an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY as an alias for the ROWID, and [documents the ROWID selection algorithm](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) as:

> If no ROWID is specified on the insert, or if the specified ROWID has a value of NULL, then an appropriate ROWID is created automatically. The usual algorithm is to give the newly created row a ROWID that is one larger than the largest ROWID in the table prior to the insert. If the table is initially empty, then a ROWID of 1 is used.

So, this is expected.  Unless you delete the rows with the highest ID, a new ID will be used.

Comment: Even if I delete the last entry (highest ID), it will skip that ID on next entry. But I am seeing from the documentation that AUTOINCREMENT is causing that: